# Mixing an absolute column and relative row reference within a VBA script in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched high and low across the entire internet for this, but I can't seem to find an answer.  Within an Excel VBA script, I want to load a variable from the value of a cell on the spreadsheet.  The issue is that I want to specify that cell as being on the same row as the cell that is using this VBA formula, but with a specific column.  Basically I want within the script to load the value from column "C" of the active row.

In a particular cell, I'll enter the formula =myfunc()

Within myfunc():

If I use `varName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value2` I'll end up with relative row and columns.

If I use `varName = ActiveCell.Cells(1, 3).Value2`, I get absolute row and columns.

I want to load the value from the cell in column "C" (aka 3) of the current row containing "=myfunc()" into varName regardless the row or column of the cell containing this formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, don't use `ActiveCell` - that's not necessarily the cell with the formula

Something like:

```
varName = Application.Caller.EntireRow.Cells(3).Value
```

should work.  Or you can use `Application.ThisCell` in place of `Application.Caller`

Comment: You nailed it my friend!  Thanks!